# Redirect loop error when trying to open a txt file on G cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to view some .txt files on my Google Cloud Storage. But when I click the links, the page goes to a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error on Chrome.

The .txt links were working fine early Dec which is the last time I accessed them, but from then till now something broke.

Comment: Update, if I click on the 'shared publicly' checkbox, a link appears at the side and I can access the .txt files that way. But the main link is still broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by clearing your cookies, and it should never happen again in this browser.

If you'd prefer not to clear all of your cookies, you can search for cookies scoped to "storage.cloud.google.com" in Chrome, and clear the "cds" cookies (I suspect you have two - you can actually get by with just clearing the older one, which should be the one whose domain is "storage.cloud.google.com" rather than ".storage.cloud.google.com".